# How to design non-windowed Gtk.Frame in Glade?

Tags: application-development, gtk, quickly, pygtk, glade

I'm building a ToDo app for personal purposes, and I'm using Quickly and Glade.

I want it to display a list of the pending to-do elements. The problem I'm having is that I can't find the way to create a single Frame (not inside another window) with some other widgets inside to dynamically add them to a VBox that I already have created in Glade.

Is there a way to do it or do I have to create the Frame in the code?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to add another window, a box, and a frame. Then re-parent the frame or the box.  I sort of did that here: https://github.com/jrgifford/cryptogram

Comment: Or build the frame and child widgets by hand. Don't be afraid to do some actual coding.